# How to append "OR" conditional operator to MySQL dynamic queries (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a dynamic query string, and I'm having problems on how to append an OR conditional operator.

It's easy enough for AND operator, like so:

```
$base_query = "SELECT * FROM `tropical_fruits` WHERE 1 "
```

And then, to append another query, I just do the following:

```
$query_1 = "AND `colour` = $fruit_colour;
$final_query = $base_query . $query_1;
```

But how do I append an OR operator?

For example, if I simply append OR like so:

```
$query_1 = "OR `colour` = $fruit_colour;
```

... the query is not producing the correct result anymore (meaning that the query is going to retrieve every record in the table).

So the question is...

***what should the base query be, so that it is flexible enough to append either or an AND and/or OR condition, bearing in mind that the user can submit two OR conditions***

I'm sorry if this question is not clear... I'm having difficulties trying to explain it!! ;-)

The main thin is, I'm writing a function that will accept search queries, and return the result. The search function need to be able to accept queries like:

```
 AND WHERE = 
 AND WHERE LIKE
 OR WHERE =
 OR WHERE LIKE
```

Basically, I need to append the above queries to a base query that looks like this:

```
$base_query = 'SELECT * FROM `' . $table_name . '` WHERE 1 ';
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the expected output? what exactly you mean by "is not producing the correct result anymore"?

Comment: Read more about logical expressions.

Comment: I've edited my question to give a bit more clarity for what I'm after. Apologies if it's still not clear! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition comes next to "OR" is always optional. In your base query, "where" condition will allow all the documents in your table. Still you want to limit result of select query
try as follows,

```
$query_1 = " AND (`colour` = $fruit_colour OR 'type'=$some_type)";
```

You can limit result by using mixed parenthesis and condition operators.

And be sure execution priority of these operator.

Comment: Thanks, although not the exact answer, your tips helped me to come up with a solution on how I can dynamically append AND and OR statements together without breaking the MySQL query. So I'm going to mark yours as the answer! :-)

Answer (score 3):

> SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE LastName='Svendson'AND (FirstName='Tove'
>   OR FirstName='Ola')